# Finding IP of server for minecraft server

Tags: windows, bash, webserver, minecraft

I am trying to view the server IP because it wont let me runipconfig for some reason. Anyone have any other ideas how to find it? tried using xdg-open with whatsmyip.com but it wont open

My Goal is run a minecraft server on a webserver i have access to but cannot tell what url or IP to out in the address bar in minecraft.
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq3y5.png)

Answer (score -1):

in linux, correct command is "ifconfig -a" instead of "ipconfig /all" in windows

Comment: This will not work if the server is behind a NAT.